# Extract filename from directory in R on Linux Server

Tags: python, r, path, basename

I would like to extract filename from directory in R on Linux Server.

The basename function in R will only work on Windows system. In Python, there is a package called ntpath that could extract filename from directory very easily on Linux environment.

```
path <- "C:\\Data\\2019\\201907\\20190726\\myfile.txt"
name <- basename(path)
```

The expected output would be myfile.txt. However, this will only work in Windows system but not Linux server. Basename function on Linux Server will give the full path.

Comment: ```basename ``` in R uses ```/``` as default separator

Comment: R recognizes `/` on windows, too, so you can safely use `/` on every system without risk of OS-splintering. If you are not certain which format you're getting, you might be able to safely use `gsub("\\\\", "/", path)` to convert backslash-based paths to forward-slash. (Though I find it curious that on windows, `basename` accepts both, but on linux, it only accepts forward-slash ... \*shrug\*, more reason to only ever use forward-slash.)

Answer (score 3):

Since R recognizes `/` as default separator on Linux and `\\` as one of the separators on Windows apart from `/`, you may work around it in the following fashion.

```
path <- "C:\\Data\\2019\\201907\\20190726\\myfile.txt"
path <- gsub("\\", "/", path, fixed=TRUE)
name <- basename(path)
```

Happy coding :)

Comment: (Disregard my since-deleted comment, I skipped `fixed=TRUE` ...)